# Show that a function is trivial on the unit circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f$ : $\mathbb{S^1}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $\forall$ $z,z'$ $\in$ $\mathbb{S^1}$, $f(zz')=f(z)+f(z')$

Let $K=\{{e^{i\theta},\frac{\theta}{2\pi} \in \mathbb{Q}}\}$, show that f is trivial on $K$ i.e, $f(z)=0$  $\forall z \in K$

Also what topological property $K$ enjoys inside  $\mathbb{S^1}$ $?$ I dont know how to start the proof and i need some hints please !!

Comment: It should be clear that no non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb R$ with addition is compact. Thus, the image of a continuous homomorphism from a compact group must be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=1$, then $f(1z')=f(1)+f(z')$ and so $f(1)=0$. So, you know at least one element is always mapped to $0$. That's a good starting point for you I think.

Next, try looking at the case that $z=z'$. What about $z'=z^2$, $z'=z^n$?

Comment: Ok.. then $f(z^n)=nf(z)$, also $f(0)=f(0)+f(0) then f(0)=0$ and by this i can conclude that $\forall$ $z$,$f(z)=0 $ since $f(0.z)=f(0)+f(z)=f(0)$

so what is the point of the problem considering the set $K$ ?

Comment: Be careful. Does the circle contain 0?

Comment: @RamyTanios: $0\notin\Bbb S^1$ hence $f(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: yes you are right thank you, but how can i use the fact that $\frac{\theta}{2\pi} is rational

Comment: Well, if $x = \theta/2\pi =p/q$ is rational, then what is $q(\theta/2\pi)$? How about $\exp(i\theta)^q$?

Comment: @DanRust Since $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$=$\frac{p}{q}$ then $\theta=\frac{2p\pi}{q}$ and $f[(e^{\frac{2ip\pi}{q}})^q]=f(e^{2ip\pi})=f((-1)^p)=pf(-1)=0=qf(e^{i\theta})$ so $f(e^{i\theta})$=0

Comment: Small nitpick: $e^{ki2\pi}=1$ for all integers $k$, not $(-1)^k$. Other than that, you're reasoning is right!

Comment: To finish, use the fact that $K$ is a dense subset of $S^1$ (you should show this is true). Then use the fact that a continuous map on a Hausdorff space is completely determined by its value on a dense subset.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}e^{\pm i\pi}=\cos(\pm\pi)+i\sin(\pm\pi)\pi=-1\in K\text{ because } \frac{\pm\pi}{2\pi}\in\Bbb Q\\e^{0i}=\cos 0+i\sin 0=1\in K \text{ because } \frac{0}{2\pi}\in\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$
Besides $f(\pm z)=f(\pm1)+f(z)\Rightarrow f(\pm1)=0$.

From $$\pi=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\\\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\\\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{\pi}{8}\\......\\......\\\frac{\pi}{2^n}=\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$$ we get easily
$$f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})= f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})= f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{8}})=….= f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2^n}})=0\text { for all } n$$
Furthermore $f(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})=f(\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{2})=f(i)=0$.

You can finish now with $f(z)=0$ thinking a little more.

On the other hand $K$ is easily seen to be a subgroup of the group multiplicative $\Bbb S^1$. Because of
$z\in K\iff rz\in K$ for all non-zero rational $r$ one can prove that $K$ is dense in $\Bbb S^1$.